# What would be the method to pass a CSS attribute to save it into a MySQL database?

Tags: php, javascript, xml-parsing, session-variables

I'm creating a small web application that will let the user resize and reposition div elements through Javascript. Then, when the user hits the 'submit changes' button, I would like to save the new CSS attributes for those div elements (mostly width, top, left) into a MySQL database via PHP. What do you think would be the 'best' method to accomplish this?

I've been googling for a while and I've found that hidden input elements would work to save those values and pass them via the POST method. I also found that using $_SESSION variables would also work, although I'm not sure how I would grab those values resulting from Javascript and pass them to PHP. And I was myself wondering if maybe creating and XML file through Javascript and then making PHP handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use XML for this? that would be like using a sledgehammer to hammer some carpet nails.

I would use JSON for this - create a JSON object which stores information about the CSS rules, then upload that to the server using whatever tech you want (form, Ajax, whatever), and store it as a text type in the database.

Comment: JSON, interesting... I'm googling this now, as it's new to me. This is a good start, thanks!

Comment: After some hours of fun research I'm finding this JSON object stuff fascinating, and it's exactly what I needed. Thank you, Kae!